# Pascal Triangle Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new to python so i would be very grateful if you could help me.
i need to make a program that gives me pascal triangle lines by writing a number and clicking a button
i have a problem with pulling out a number from entry.get. here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk

root=Tk()
w = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 500
h = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 250
root.geometry('700x500+{}+{}'.format(w,h))
root.title("Главное окно")


def PrintPasTriangle(rows):
    row = [1]
    for i in range(rows):
        print(row)
        row = [sum(x) for x in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]

label = Label(text = PrintPasTriangle(10))



def show_message():
    e1 = entry
    e1.insert = (PrintPasTriangle(10))


entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

btn = ttk.Button(text="Click", command=show_message)
btn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

label = ttk.Label()
label.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=9)
label = Label(text = PrintPasTriangle(10))
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `entry.get()` to get the content in the entry box and use `int()` to convert the content to an integer as long as the content is a valid integer in string.  I would suggest you to search some beginner tutorials on tkinter from the internet.

Comment: You need to `return` `row` and insert is not treated like an attribute, it is a method so it should be `e1.insert('end',PrintPasTriangle(10))`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Redo: To get input working. I commented out line 34 and 34. I also removed `show_message` function. It is up to you.

I added `from math import factorial` Then I changed formula for pascal triangle in `PrintPasTriangle` function.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from math import factorial

root=Tk()
w = (root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - 500
h = (root.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - 250
root.geometry('700x500+{}+{}'.format(w,h))
root.title("Главное окно")

ent = IntVar()
 
def PrintPasTriangle(rows):    
    for i in range(rows):       
        for j in range(rows-i+1):
            print(end=" ")

        for j in range(i+1):
            print(factorial(i)//(factorial(j)*factorial(i-j)), end=" ")

        print() 
    label1.config(text=f"Pascal Triangle:  {ent.get()}", font=("Calibri,15,Bold"))


entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=ent)
entry.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

btn = ttk.Button(root,text="Click", command=lambda: PrintPasTriangle(ent.get()))
btn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text='label')
label1.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=9)

#label2 = Label(root, text = str(ent.get()))
#label2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Result screenshot:

[image]